# Solr for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, solr

I am using the solr-for-wordpress plugin, but when i run indexing all posts, i am getting an error like:

> "400" Status: Illegal character
>   ((CTRL-CHAR, code 7)) at [row,col
>   {unknown-source}]: [38878,5]

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue due to certain characters in your content needing to be properly escaped before being submitted in XML format to the server.

Here's an example of how someone handled this need in Java:

[Update with Invalid Control Character Crashes Solr](http://mysolr.com/tips/update-with-invalid-control-character-crashes-solr/)